# regular expression to check input on multiline textbox

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox, multiline

Lets say I have a multiline textbox that I would like to have checked for say, 1-2 digits over a max of 5 lines.  I found a regular expression pattern answered on another similar question on here but it was not working for me even after modifying it a number of times.

I'm currently using the following without success.

```
Dim textCheck As New Regex("(^\d{1,2}$\r?\n?){0,5}", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Could somebody help me out with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're wanting to match a list of 1 to 2 digit numbers separated by a newline, up to five?  if so, this should work.  the last newline is optional and if theres anything else in the string it doesn't match.  (for this, don't use RegexOptions.Multiline)

I checked this with C#, so I'm not sure if the escape characters are correct.  i noticed yours only had 1 slash before the d.  in c# you need two, but i removed it from this to make it look like yours.

```
Dim textCheck As New Regex("^\d{1,2}((\r|\n|\r\n)\d{1,2}){0,4}(\r|\n|\r\n)?$")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Grab a copy of RegEx Designer. it's free and worth it's wieght for this kind of thing.

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/?from=RegexDesigner

Then, I think what you might want is something like this

(^\d{1,2}\r?\n?){0,5}\z

and then test that the match includes the entire input. The $ in the middle won't help, the \z forces the match to the end of string. There's probably some details I've missed though. Again, RegExDesigner makes playing with regexes sooooo much more enjoyable!

Comment: Nice, thank you very much.  I've been contemplating looking for a good free regex designer.  I'll give that a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: I think this might match "123456" since the newlines are optional.

Comment: Yep, this was a bit closer than what I was working with but still didn't quite capture what I needed.  Thanks for your help and the link to RegEx designer though.

Comment: @mark, hmmm, yep, that would seem to be the case. Regex's always seem to be fraught with the "devil in the details"